# Кеширование страниц

Tags: python, django, кэширование

Задание у меня такое: "Измените работу главной страницы сайта так, чтобы список записей хранился в кеше и обновлялся раз в 20 секунд. В качестве ключа используйте index_page. Напишите тесты, которые проверяют работу кеша."

По теории знаю 2 способа добавления кеширования:
1.Добавление специального декоратора во view функции
2.В шаблоны страницы

В обоих случаях при добавлении кеширования падают тесты.

Эту тему я только начал изучать и не пойму почему падают тесты.

Вот первый способ добавления кеширования:

```
    ...
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

MAX_NUMB_ENTRIES = 10


@cache_page(20 * 15)
def index(request):
    pathname = 'posts/index.html'
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, MAX_NUMB_ENTRIES)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'posts': post_list,
    }
    return render(request, pathname, context)
...
```

При запуске тестов вот такой трейсбек

```
ERROR: test_first_page_contains_ten_records (posts.tests.test_views.PaginatorViewsTest) (reverse_name='/')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\hw04_tests\yatube\posts\tests\test_views.py", line 173, in _test_pagination
    len(response.context['page_obj']), expected_count
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_post_list_page_show_correct_context (posts.tests.test_views.PostsPagesTests)
Шаблон post_list сформирован с правильным контекстом.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\hw04_tests\yatube\posts\tests\test_views.py", line 131, in test_post_list_page_show_correct_context
    first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

======================================================================
FAIL: test_pages_uses_correct_template_quest (posts.tests.test_views.PostsPagesTests) (reverse_name='/')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\hw04_tests\yatube\posts\tests\test_views.py", line 75, in test_pages_uses_correct_template_quest
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template)
  File "D:\Dev\hw04_tests\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 639, in assertTemplateUsed
    self.fail(msg_prefix + "No templates used to render the response")
AssertionError: No templates used to render the response

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 31 tests in 0.296s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Если пойти другим путем, добавлением в шаблон:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% load cache %}
{% block title %}Последние обновления на сайте{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <main>
        <div class="container py-5">
            <h1>Последние обновления на сайте</h1>
            {% cache 20 index_page %}
            {% for post in page_obj %}
                {% include 'includes/post.html' %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% include 'posts/includes/paginator.html' %}
            {% endcache %}
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

выходит вот такой трейсбек.

```
ERROR: test_pages_uses_correct_template_quest (posts.tests.test_views.PostsPagesTests) (reverse_name='/')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\hw04_tests\yatube\posts\tests\test_views.py", line 81, in test_pages_uses_correct_template_quest
    self.post.image,
  File "D:\Dev\hw04_tests\yatube\posts\tests\test_views.py", line 122, in _assert_post_has_attribs
    self.assertEqual(post.id, id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста может я что-то упускаю?
Тесты вроде написаны правильно, рабочие.
Что не так? Куда копать мне?

Answer (score 2):

Проблему падающих тестов решил путем добавления кеширования в шаблон. Ну а потом в методы, в которых возникали ошибки, вставлял `cache.clear()`. тесты проходят нормально. Также можно вставить в метод `setUp()`.

В дальнейшем если вы захотите сделать тест на присутствия кеширования в шаблоне, у вас возможно появятся тоже ошибки из других тестов.
Лучше создать в этом же методе новый пост и вставить очистку кеширования в самом тесте.

```
def test_cache_index(self):
        """Проверка хранения и очищения кэша для index."""
        response = self.authorized_author.get(reverse('posts:index'))
        posts = response.content
        Post.objects.create(
            text='test_new_post',
            author=self.author,
        )
        response_old = self.authorized_author.get(reverse('posts:index'))
        old_posts = response_old.content
        self.assertEqual(old_posts, posts)
        cache.clear()
        response_new = self.authorized_author.get(reverse('posts:index'))
        new_posts = response_new.content
        self.assertNotEqual(old_posts, new_posts)
```

Оставлю здесь вдруг кому понадобится.